# Trouble while executing mssql query on tomcat 8.5

Tags: java, sql-server, tomcat

I have some trouble while executing a query on tomcat 8.5. It is a jsp file named index.jsp and all I want to do is running a sql query on tomcat server. Here is my code:

```
<%@ page import="java.io.IOException" %>
<%@ page import="java.sql.*" %>
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<%
    try{
        Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
        Connection connection = 
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://127.0.0.1; 
databaseName=veritabanı;" +
                " username=user; password=psw;");
        Statement statement = 
connection.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY, 
ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
        ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery("select * from tablo 
where id = 10");
        while(resultSet.next()){
            out.println(resultSet.getArray(0) + " " + 
resultSet.getArray(1));
        }
    }catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }catch(SQLException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }catch(ClassNotFoundException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
%>
</body>
</html>
```

I think the problem is about the ResultSet. So I found some another ways to create statement:

```
createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);

createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
```

But these did not worked as well. And here is the error I got:

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: This operation is not supported.
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(SQLServerException.java:191)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerResultSet.NotImplemented(SQLServerResultSet.java:765)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerResultSet.getArray(SQLServerResultSet.java:2762)
at org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:130)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:443)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:386)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:330)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:504)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:650)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:790)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: what you expect `resultSet.getArray(0)` to return ?

Comment: @YCF_L I just change those as 'resultSet.getArray(1)' and 'resultSet.getArray(2)' and again same problem. It should return name and surname column from my table on sql database.

Comment: why you don't use `resultSet.getString("name"); resultSet.getString("surname");` then

Comment: @YCF_L Okey it worked, thanks. But what is the difference? Why the first element of array is not name and second one is surname? What is the reason that I got this error.

Comment: because your query return all the fields and not an Array ;)

Comment: @YCF_L Now i see, thanks again.